# using string variable in sql query string having column name in select query

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to put column name in variable then i m using this string in sql query as:

```
string s="ID";

string sql="select '"+s+"' from table_name where name='abhk'";

cmd=new SqlCommand(sql_pics, con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

*it says incorrect syntax error near ID*`ID is column name.`

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `string sql = "select "+s+" from table_name where name='abhk'";` column name cannot and should not be a string enclosed in `single quotes`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
string sql = "select ID from table_name where name='abhk'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query would look like the following using your current logic:

```
select 'ID' from table_name where name = 'abhk'
```

You would need to change your sql string to:

```
string sql="select " + s + " from table_name where name='abhk'";
```

However, this is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes will not work here, but I'd suggest putting brackets before and after the column name, rather than nothing, in case the column name contains spaces or special characters:

```
string sql="select ["+s+"] from table_name where name='abhk'";
```